# Anyway to get string from variable name?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

Say I have my class

```
@interface Person : NSObject { NSString *name; }
```

I need to get the name of NSString's within my class

```
Person *person = [[Person alloc] init];
NSLog(@"Name of variable %s\n", _NameofVariable_(person->name));
```

**Thanks for the answers, here's the solution I came up from the replies**

```
//returns nil if property is not found
-(NSString *)propertyName:(id)property {  
    unsigned int numIvars = 0;
    NSString *key=nil;
    Ivar * ivars = class_copyIvarList([self class], &numIvars);
    for(int i = 0; i < numIvars; i++) {
        Ivar thisIvar = ivars[i];
        if ((object_getIvar(self, thisIvar) == property)) {
            key = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:ivar_getName(thisIvar)];
            break;
        }
    } 
    free(ivars);
    return key;
}
```

Comment: you must also `free(ivars)`, or else you'll leak the array.

Comment: good catch, updated to reflect that.

Comment: Won't this just return the first name of any property on the class that matches the value you pass in? 

Example: https://gist.github.com/robskillington/684796bae2dd95592919

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the names of a class's instance variables with the [Objective-C runtime API](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html) function `class_copyIvarList`. However, this is rather involved, rarely done and almost never the best way to accomplish something. If you have a more specific goal in mind than mere curiosity, it might be a good idea to ask about how to accomplish it in Objective-C.

Also, incidentally, `person.name` doesn't specify an instance variable in Objective-C — it's a property call. The instance variable would be `person->name`.

Comment: I didn't know you could access instance variables that way. Will likely never use it, but good to know.

Comment: @Brandon you can do that because Objective-C objects are really just structs.  :)

Comment: @Brandon, you do need to be careful when using the `person->name` idiom, because whereas `person.name` takes advantage of nil object behavior and would simply return `nil` if `person` is `nil`, `person->name` will likely crash if `person` is `nil`, just like good ol' C or C++.

Answer (score 37):

As easy as

`#define VariableName(arg) (@""#arg)`

Then you do:

```
NSObject *obj;
NSString *str = VariableName(obj);
NSLog(@"STR %@", str);//obj
```

Comment: Has anyone tried this?  Try  VariableName(here_s_a_random_string_that_s_not_a_var)
This isn't a way to get a property or ivar to return it's name.  This is just a way to save you from typing @"" around some text - and instead you're using VariableName().  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Note if you pass a macro it will return the macro name not the object that macro is set to.

Comment: How do this in Swift for NSObject?

Answer (score 2):

You might use preprocessor stringification and a bit of string twiddling:

```
NSUInteger lastIndexAfter(NSUInteger start, NSString *sub, NSString *str) {
    NSRange found = [str rangeOfString:sub options:NSBackwardsSearch];
    if(found.location != NSNotFound) {
        NSUInteger newStart = NSMaxRange(found);
        if(newStart > start)
            return newStart;
    }
    return start;
}

NSString *lastMember(NSString *fullName) {
    if(!fullName) return nil;

    NSUInteger start = 0;
    start = lastIndexAfter(start, @".", fullName);
    start = lastIndexAfter(start, @"->", fullName);

    return [fullName substringFromIndex: start];
}

#define NSStringify(v) (@#v)
#define _NameofVariable_(v) lastMember(NSStringify(v))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the person object is exposed as a property of the class, you can use objc_msgSend to get the value.

So, if you could access person using

```
[object person]
```

You could also do

```
objc_msgSend(object, "person")
```

For more details on message sending, including how to pass arguments to methods, see the [Objective-C Runtime Programming Guide section on Messaging](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtHowMessagingWorks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH104-SW1)

Answer (score 0):

The following works as a macro:

```
#define STRINGIZE(x) #x
```