# How does one get the name of an instance variable in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, ios, variables, encoding, metadata

I'm trying to get the name of an instance variable from an Objective-C class. Say I have a class that looks like this:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSSNumber *myVar;

@end
```

Given myVar, I want to get "myVar". Then I could use it in a log like this:

```
MyClass *myObject = [[myClass alloc] init];
NSLog(@"The variable is named: %@", getVarName([myObject myVar]));
```

Then the log would say: `The variable is named myVar`. Thank you for your help!

PS The reason I want to do this is to create a method for encoding variables for archiving. So when I write my `encodeWithCoder` method I can just do something like this:

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    NSArray *varsForEncoding = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:var1, var2, var3, nil];
    for (NSObject *var in varsForEncoding)
    {
        [aCoder encodeObject:var forKey:getVarName(var)];
    }
}
```

Then do the reverse in `initWithCoder`. That would prevent typos screwing this up, e.g. using key `@"myVar"` when encoding but typing `@"mVar"` in the initializer.

Comment: Similar question and answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484778/anyway-to-get-string-from-variable-name/22035149

Answer (score 7):

You can try with this method:

```
//returns nil if property is not found
-(NSString *)propertyName:(id)property {  
  unsigned int numIvars = 0;
  NSString *key=nil;
  Ivar * ivars = class_copyIvarList([self class], &numIvars);
  for(int i = 0; i < numIvars; i++) {
    Ivar thisIvar = ivars[i];
    if ((object_getIvar(self, thisIvar) == property)) {
        key = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:ivar_getName(thisIvar)];
        break;
    }
  } 
  free(ivars);
  return key;
}
```

([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484778/anyway-to-get-string-from-variable-name))

Comment: Worked great, thanks. I just had to link to libobjc.dylib and import <objc/runtime.h>.

Answer (score 0):

**Just use a single line of code as this.**

```
#define NSLogVariable(x) NSLog( @"Variable : %s = %@",#x,x)
```

**define it along with the headers as a macro and use it anywhere.**
eg:

```
NSString *myObj=@"abcd";
NSLogVariable(myObj);
```

it will display

```
Variable : myObj = "abcd"
```

**Hope it help some one.**