# How could I get the property name of the current UITextField a user is in as a string?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, nsstring, uitextfield

I am using the following method:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range
replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

Before, in order to find the current text field I was in, I was able to write something like this:

```
if (textField == self.textPlaceID)
{
    //Do something
}
```

Is there a way to grab the name of my `textField` as a string? I am not asking to take what the user has typed in that `textField`, I'd like to be able to just get the property name of if. I need it to then concatenate it with some other strings. I am working on making a dynamic method call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primarily assign unique tags to each of the textFields (eg 1,2,3.....) avoid 0 for a textField tag

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
NSDictionary *dictionary ; //declare it in .h interface

dictionary =  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"textPlaceID",[NSNumber numberWithInt:1], @"textPlaceID2",[NSNumber numberWithInt:2],nil]; // add textField as object and tag as keys
}
```

further..

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range
replacementString:(NSString *)string{

NSString *textFieldPropertyName = [dictionary objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:textField.tag]];

}
```

Comment: Do upvote this answer.so it might be helpful for future help seeking users :)

Answer (score 4):

`UITextField`s do not have "names". You can give your text field  a `tag` and use that.

Also, note that `(pointer == pointer)` will only return true if you are referencing the same **objects**, not equivalent values.

Here is how to use the tag: in Interface Builder, give each text field a tag, or if you create your text fields programmatically, set `textField.tag = someInt;` I usually use macros to make the code more readable:

```
#define kNameTextField 2
#define kAddressTextField 3

...

if (textField.tag == kNameTextField) ...
```

With lots of fields like that, I prefer enums:

```
typedef enum {
  kNameTextField = 2, 
  kAddressTextField, 
  kPhoneTextField // etc
} Fields;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get name of property (in your case textField property) using this code:

```
-(NSString *)propertyName:(id)property {  
    unsigned int numIvars = 0;
    NSString *key=nil;
    Ivar * ivars = class_copyIvarList([self class], &numIvars);
    for(int i = 0; i < numIvars; i++) {
    Ivar thisIvar = ivars[i];
    if ((object_getIvar(self, thisIvar) == property)) {
        key = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:ivar_getName(thisIvar)];
        break;
    }
} 
    free(ivars);
    return key;
}
```

Remember to import:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
```

Just call:

```
NSLog(@"name = %@", [self propertyName:self.textField]);
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484778/anyway-to-get-string-from-variable-name)