# Swift: Convert object instance name to String for use as key

Tags: swift

Given `var varName = "varValue"`, is there a way in Swift to convert the variable name to `String` at runtime? For example in this case I would get back `"varName"`.

I already know about `Mirror` APIs for reflection in Swift. That allows me to iterate over the properties of a given class but I would like to apply this to `self` for any given class. I want to use this to generate String keys automatically for any given object (irrespective of which class it belongs to)

```
extension UIView {
   var key: String {
      return "" //TODO: Convert self to varName as String
   }
}

// Usage
let customView = UIView()
customView.key // should be "customView"
```

Comment: I don't know if this is possible, but I do know that this is not the way you should be tackling this. On runtime you just shouldn't care about variable names.

Comment: `key` is not a `func`

Comment: @SanderSaelmans I am open to alternate suggestion which lets me have a unique constant key for the use case in the question. I don't care about the variable name. I care about a unique key in the given context

Comment: @NumanTariq If all you want is a unique key, `UIView` has a `tag` property for that exact purpose.

Comment: @JohannesFahrenkrug I do not want to assign the unique key manually. I am trying to find a way for objects to return a unique key that does not change.

Comment: Something like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22035149/1071489 would be ideal

Comment: What do you need the “key” for?

Comment: In Swift, property names are purely a convenience for the programmer (so as to give human names to memory addresses), and they don't exist in the program at runtime. What actually are you trying to accomplish by this? There maybe other ways to achieve your goal.

Comment: I need the 'key' to be different for 2 instances of UIView. I want that key to be the same every time for that particular instance i.e. the key shouldn't change if the app is restarted or the view instance is destroyed and recreated. I can use this key as key in caching. Another use case can be to use it as accessibilityIdentifier to help with UITesting

Comment: @NumanTariq Ah, OK. You should update the question with these specific requirements. The best solution would be to subclass `UIView` and pass in the identifier you want each instance to have. That way you can set up the `accessibilityIdentifier` right in the init method. Also, as a general rule, you want to rather make things explicit and easy-to-understand than to use "magic". It's harder to debug and much harder and more unexpected for yourself and other developers to understand.

Comment: @NumanTariq Why don't you just use the `.tag` property??

Comment: "*I want that key to be the same every time for that particular instance i.e. the key shouldn't change if the app is restarted or the view instance is destroyed and recreated*" – but if the instance is destroyed and recreated, it isn't the same instance. Also what should happen for `let x = customView; x.key`? `x` points to the same instance as `customView`, but it's a different variable name.

Comment: (on a tangent, purely for fun [a while ago I implemented a prototype](https://github.com/hamishknight/swift/commit/aa5eef4b61bd6863f08f1c5104bff325db5ca359#diff-79c589aa443482225d11fdd657f62f6eR1) for a magic literal `#name(x)` which would evaluate to a string literal of the name of the declaration `x` refers to – I'm not convinced it would make a great language feature though)

Answer (score 0):

**Update**:

The OP added this comment clarifying the requirements:

> I need the 'key' to be different for 2 instances of UIView. I want that key to be the same every time for that particular instance i.e. the key shouldn't change if the app is restarted or the view instance is destroyed and recreated. I can use this key as key in caching. Another use case can be to use it as accessibilityIdentifier to help with UITesting.

In that case, I suggest to not even think about using ✨magic✨. Just explicitly give your view instances an identifier. You could also totally just reuse existing properties on `UIView` like `tag` or `accessibilityIdentifier`. If that's not enough or not convenient enough, subclass:

```
class IdentifiableView: UIView {
    public private(set) var identifier: String

    init(frame: CGRect, identifier: String) {
        self.identifier = identifier
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.accessibilityIdentifier = identifier
    }

    init() {
        fatalError("Must use init(frame:identifier:)")
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        fatalError("Must use init(frame:identifier:)")
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("Must use init(frame:identifier:)")
    }
}

// Usage
let firstView = IdentifiableView(frame: .zero, identifier: "First View")
firstView.identifier
firstView.identifier

let otherView = IdentifiableView(frame: .zero, identifier: "Second View")
otherView.identifier
otherView.identifier
```

---

If, according to your comment, you simply want "objects to return a unique key that does not change", you could simply use their memory address:

```
extension UIView {
    var key: String {
        return "\(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())"
    }
}

let firstView = UIView()
firstView.key // -> "0x00007fbc29d02f10"
firstView.key // -> "0x00007fbc29d02f10"

let otherView = UIView()
otherView.key // -> "0x00007fbc29d06920"
otherView.key // -> "0x00007fbc29d06920"
```

For each instance of `UIView` you create this will return a unique value that will not change.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, the key will change for each instantiation?

Comment: @NumanTariq Exactly. You said "I am trying to find a way for objects to return a unique key that does not change." That key naturally is their memory address on the heap.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish here but I think you can convert variable name to string in Swift with `#keyPath(propertyName)` but it requires you to add `@objc` to your var.

For example

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    @objc var name: String = "John"
}

print(#keyPath(MyViewController.name))
```

prints `name` in the console.

Comment: Yes but this won't fit in the sample use case I specified in the question. The ideal solution will work as per the usage in question

Comment: The question pertains to an object's name, not it's vairables'